# Azure Functions with Multiple Python Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am unable to import my other python file in the **init**.py file. I have tried importing that according to the same way as mentioned in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

This is my **init**.py file:

```
    import logging

    import azure.functions as func
    from . import test


    def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
        print("test")
        num = sum_num(2, 3)
        print(num)
        name = req.params.get('name')
        if not name:
            try:
                req_body = req.get_json()
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                name = req_body.get('name')

        if name:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
            )
```

this is my test.py file with very basic sum function:

```
    def sum_num(val1, val2):
        print("inside function")
        return val1 + val2
```

Please help me out how to import this sum_num function in my **init**.py file.

[the folder structure is also fine as you can see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU9Hf.png)

[Error i am getting in the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2SVM.png)

Comment: Did you try `test.sum_num`? intead of just `sum_num`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM thanks mate, it worked
so i have to use test.sum_num instead of sum_num

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Could you please post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @JimXu Done, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have already imported the module using

```
from . import test
```

so in order to access the function from the module you should use

```
num = test.sum_num(2, 3)
```

Alternatively you can import only the function from the module.

```
from .test import sum_num
```

Answer (score 0):

**BEWARE**

The first solution presented by Abdul works indeed : `from . import test`, provided that you have a `test.py` at the same level with the `__init__.py`.

However, the solution `from .test import sum_num` does not work.

I both solutions and the latter does not work.

Indeed, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior), the only way for relative import is this one (see in the docs):

```
 from . import example #(relative)
```

My testing environment was Linux (with Consumption Plan) + Python `3.10.4`